# Error ITMS-90045 Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, submission

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this error in Xcode when attempting to submit a build of app?

ERROR ITMS-90045. "Invalid code signing identities. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, key' com.apple.security.app-sandbox' in 'Payload/SprityBird.app/SprityBird' is not supported."

Any comments would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you manually add something to the entitlements file or copy an entitlements file from an OS X target?

Comment: Thanks Brad,
I removed an item from the entitlements file in Xcode and now the app has been submitted for review.